# How to run selenium 2.0 script in jenkins

Tags: selenium, jenkins

I have selenium webdriver script, and i want to run the script in jenkins. how to configure in jenkins. what steps i need to fallow? i am new to jenkins, can any one tell me the step by step procedure to fallow.

Answer (score 2):

If you're running Jenkins on a unix machine, create a new job:
 Click on New Job, Type a name and click on Build a free-style software project

Then add a 'build' step called 'Execute shell'. (For windows you can use Windows Batch command).

Using that you can run the selenium standalone server jar to execute the your selenium script.

For example: 
java -version && java -jar /Applications/SeleniumRC/selenium-server-standalone-2.12.0.jar -trustAllSSLCertificates -htmlSuite "*googlechrome" "https://user:password@www.example.com/" "examplesuite.html" "result_file.html"

Other option would be to go to Configure Jenkins -> Configure Plugins and install Hudson Seleniumhq plugin and use the build step provided by them when configuring the jenkins job.

You might also want to create a Post-build Action to show reports. If you install Selenium HTML report plugin from the aforementioned Manage Plugins page, you can then add 'Publish selenium report' Post-build step.